# Wordpress HTTPS not working if HTTPS request from Cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront

My website is hosted on AWS and is using Cloudfront in which all the HTTPS transactions will be done in the CloudFront level.

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; ?>
```

When I check the port, it returns 80 as SSL is not configured on 443 port.

Wordpress is configured to check the port 443 for HTTPS and due to this even after changing site URL and admin URL to https, the site does not change URL of the assets (js,css) to https. It changes to https only when it detects 443 port.

Currently, we have tried all possible solutions from changing site & admin URL, replacing HTTP to HTTPS in DB, htaccess solutions. Is there a way to change WordPress configuration.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: hope this will help : https://raventools.com/blog/ssl-wordpress-cloudfront/

Answer (score 2):

This may help you :

Writing the following code in wp-config.php file will solve the issue.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) && "https" == $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) {
$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

Comment: Tried this too, but it still does not solve the issue.